# How to close Action Pane By clicking button in action pane Flutter Slidable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-slider

How to close Action Pane By clicking "No" button in action pane. I'm Using Flutter Slidable Package

[image]

Comment: Can you include your current code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

First try to get the SlidableController from the context and you can close with that:

```
final SlidableController? controller = Slidable.of(context);
controller?.close();
```

Comment: Not Working. I want to close end action pane on clicking "no" button

Answer (score 0):

There is an basically code which you can use

```
    SlideAction({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    VoidCallback? onTap,
    Color? color,
    Decoration? decoration,
    bool closeOnTap = _kCloseOnTap,
  })
```

This can be use to perform operation on both button on **No Button** just set **closeOnTap** to **true**

Comment: Here you can check https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SlidableAction Widget this fixed it for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).